# How JMX, actuator and prometheus connected?

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, jmx, spring-boot-actuator

I tried to browse and understand the JMX use case. But couldn't get much around it.

Issue: we have the spring boot application which has the JMX ssl sniffing issue.  The JMX remote is enabled but without SSL.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
    -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT"
```

There are 2 ways to resolve them.

1. One is to enable SSL
2. Remove the JMX

Let's say I removed the JMX params in the Java Opts, what would be the effect of this on the spring boot 2.x application?

The spring boot actuator can still expose the metrics?

tried to enable the SSL, but had ran into some issues.

removed the java opts, the sniffing issue is resolved.

Comment: For the application nothing changes. It all depends on the fact if you actually use JMX or not, that is the question that you need to answer yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I dont directly use the JMX, I wanted to know, if prometheus/actuator works  if I disable them.

Comment: As stated that depends if there are other parts in your system (not necessarily your application) use JMX. Prometheus and the Actuator can work regardless of JMX. However this has been enabled for some reason, figure out that reason.